# JOptionpane validation with double input

Tags: java, arrays, validation, double, joptionpane

I am learning java. I try to declare a double array. For the input method, I would like to use JOptionPane. My question is how can I create the validation for this array.(For example: I want to valid that the salary input will be from 2000 to 10000). I'm sorry for my bad writing. Thank you guys!

Here is my code!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Testing {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] salary = new double[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < salary.length; i++)
        {
            salary[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter Salary: "));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know [if and else](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)?

Comment: What are you going to do if the salary entered is out of range?

Comment: I know if and else, but I can not apply it in the JOtionPane. I can only use it in a given data, not by JOtionPane input

Comment: @ PM it is why I need a validation

Comment: I need to set a limit range salary. =)

Comment: and ake user to enter data again if it is invalid.

Comment: @tkay87 You cant do that validation in JOptionPane. `if (salary[i]>=2000 && salary[i] <=10000)` can be used once you collect the value and reset counter if it does not fall in to that range.

Comment: You will need to handle `NumberFormatException` in your code.  For example, if a user clicks on `Cancel` then `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` will return `null'.

Comment: Thank you Smit and PM77-1. I appreciated your help. =)

Comment: Well... You can conceivably wrap your input into `while` loop that will do the checking and then display `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` with an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you a bit to resolve your issue.

```
int i = 0;
double temp;
    while(i < salary.length) {
       // parseDouble throws NumberFormatException, handle it
      temp = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," Enter Salary: "));
       if (temp >= 2000.0 && temp <= 10000.0){
           salary[i] = temp;
           i++;     // if in range change counter to next count
          // do something
       } else {
          // do something for out of range
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond Smit

Comment: @tkay87 I updated the answer. What is the problem you are encountering? let us know to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup). Customize the code to do you particular edit.